# Change location of jQuery validation plugin error message?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin and when I add the class required to the textboxes it validates the fields. However, the error message is shown after the text box and I wonder if I can show it after the label to related textbox instead?

I have a page in an iframe and when two or more error messages are shown the form becomes too big to fit in the iframe.

My labels and textboxes:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Your Name" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="required" runat="server"/>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Your Email"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="required email" runat="server"/>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Text="Your Number"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" CssClass="required" runat="server"/>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text="Subject"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" CssClass="required" runat="server"/>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" Text="Details"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDetails" CssClass="required" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"/>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text=""  onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblResponse" CssClass="Response" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use errorPlacement. Example:

```
    $("#field-GeoLatlon").validate({
        rules: {
            "parameters[postcode]": {
                isPostcode: true
            },
            "parameters[houseno]": {
                startsWithNumber: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: errorPlacement
    });

function errorPlacement(error, element)
{
    var errorDD = $('<dd class="error"></dd>').insertAfter(element.parent('dd').next('dd'));
    error.appendTo(errorDD);
}
```

Comment: this, <dd class="error"></dd> where should I place that in the HTMl?