# Jquery Validation is not working well in single error container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to show only the First error in myErrorContainer so first i do the code like this.

```
    <div id="myErrorContainer" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"> 
  </div>
   <form method="POST" action="#" role="form" id="signup_form">
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First name</label>
  <input name="fname" id="firstname" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-
  control">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last name</label>
 <input name="lname" id="lastname" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-
 control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button id="signupSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Create 
your account</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

I want to show only the First error in myErrorContainer so first i do the code like this.

```
   <script>
     $("#signup_form").validate({
     rules: 
     {
         fname:
        {
            required: true,
        },
        lname:
        {
            required: true
        }
     },
      messages:{
        fname: 'Enter your First name',
        lname : 'Enter Last name',
      },
     showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $("#signup_form").find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    });
     $("#myErrorContainer").html("");
    if(errorList.length) {
       console.log('lenght is' + errorList.length);
        console.log(errorList[0]['message']);
        $("#myErrorContainer").html(errorList[0]['message']);
        $(errorList[0]['element']).addClass("error");
    }
    }
         });
</script>
```

The above code was working as it was suppose to be but the problem was if i leave the First name input and just focus the Last name Input and click on submit button  it shows 2 errros, for a second it shows Enter Last name then sudddenly it  show Enter your First name, so it was a focus problem and its suppose to show only the first error 'Enter your First name', Look like because of Second input focus validation run twice.
 Later i change the code in the  below way.
I Remove the Error showErrors and replace it with :

```
  $("#signup_form").validate({
     rules: 
     {
         fname:
        {
            required: true,
        },
        lname:
        {
            required: true
        }
     },
      messages:{
        fname: 'Enter your First name',
        lname : 'Enter Last name',
      },
     invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
if (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
    $("#myErrorContainer").html(validator.errorList[0].message);
    validator.errorList[0].element.focus(); //Set Focus
    $("#signup_form").find("input").each(function() {
        console.log('removing class');
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    });
}
}
         });
```

The above code works good but as its remove the focus input error just show the first error but invalidHandler does't work on keyup so if myErrorContainer has the error 'Enter your First name' and i enter First and it doesn't remove that error until i Click the submit button.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using the wrong options for this. Instead of `showErrors` or `invalidHandler`, you should be using `wrapper` and `errorLabelContainer`. See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44599142/594235