# JQuery Validator On Partial View Only Validating 1 field

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-validate

I am having an issue where only 1 field out of many is actually being validated on a PartialView.  Below is a section of the partial view that I am using (scaled back because of length):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form1').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: true,
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $('#errors').html('');
        $.each(errorList, function () {
            var element = this.element;
            var labelText = $(element).parent().parent().find('label').html();
            var error = this.message;
            $('#errors').append($("<li>").text(labelText + ": " + error));
        });
    }
});

$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

var form1 = $('#form1');
form1.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form1);
```

```
<form class="package-editor-panel col-md-12" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll;" id="form1">
<div class="package-editor-left col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Package Rule Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.PackageRuleName))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="package-editor-right col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Template Setting</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TemplateSetting)
                .DataTextField("PackageTemplateDesc")
                .DataValueField("PackageTemplateId")
                .DataSource(datasource => { datasource.Read(read => read.Action("GetPackageTemplates", "Package")); })
                .OptionLabel("Select Template Setting")
                .IgnoreCase(true)
                .AutoWidth(true)
                .AutoBind(true)
                .ValuePrimitive(true)
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="errors" style="color:red;padding-left:2em"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a sample of the model I am using:

```
public class PackageModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Template Setting")]
    public Int32? TemplateSetting { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Package Rule Name")]
    public String PackageRuleName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an onclick event that triggers the form submission which is not included above.

Since I am using Html Edit For controls both the id and name of both fields are in the generated html.  There are no other forms on the page.  Why would this only validate a single field?  Also, what can I do to ensure that all fields are validated?

The generated html markup for the form can be seen below:

```
<form class="package-editor-panel col-md-12" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll;" id="form1" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="package-editor-left col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Package Rule Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="k-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Package Rule Name field is required." id="PackageRuleName" name="PackageRuleName" value="Jason">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Claim Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ClaimTypeId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="eb8775e6-57e4-408c-9772-2239dec56c91" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Statement Claim</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Claim Type field is required." id="ClaimTypeId" name="ClaimTypeId" type="text" value="2" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ClaimTypeId").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":true,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"ClaimTypeDesc","dataValueField":"ClaimTypeId","ignoreCase":true,"value":"2","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetClaimTypes","type":"GET"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Divisions</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header k-multiselect-clearable" deselectable="on" title="" style=""><div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" deselectable="on"><ul role="listbox" deselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="DivisionIds_taglist"><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">Commercial</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li></ul><input class="k-input" style="width: 30px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="DivisionIds_taglist DivisionIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="8630464c-f969-4f52-bb7d-bb4296830bef"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span></div><select data-value-primitive="true" id="DivisionIds" multiple="multiple" name="DivisionIds" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="1" selected="">Commercial</option><option value="7">UK Commercial</option></select><span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 31px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span></div><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#DivisionIds").kendoMultiSelect({"change":function() { editorComposite.refresh('parents') },"dataBound":function() { editorComposite.set('divisions') },"autoBind":false,"autoClose":false,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"DivisionName","dataValueField":"DivisionId","highlightFirst":true,"ignoreCase":true,"placeholder":"Select Divisions","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetDivisions","data":editorComposite.clients,"type":"POST"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"value":"1"});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Parent Project</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header k-multiselect-clearable" deselectable="on" title="" style=""><div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" deselectable="on"><ul role="listbox" deselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="ParentIds_taglist"><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">AZN201612US</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">AZN201712US</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li></ul><input class="k-input" style="width: 30px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ParentIds_taglist ParentIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="e4a8591b-5fc0-4dfd-a552-fa56dee6932b"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span></div><select data-value-primitive="true" id="ParentIds" multiple="multiple" name="ParentIds" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="3635">AZN200812US</option><option value="3637">AZN200912US</option><option value="3639">AZN201112US</option><option value="3641">AZN201306US</option><option value="5011">AZN201412US</option><option value="6160">AZN201512US</option><option value="7507">AZN201612US</option><option value="8979">AZN201712US</option></select><span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 31px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span></div><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ParentIds").kendoMultiSelect({"change":function() { editorComposite.refresh('projects') },"dataBound":function() { editorComposite.set('parents') },"autoBind":false,"autoClose":false,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"ProjectNumber","dataValueField":"ProjectId","highlightFirst":true,"ignoreCase":true,"placeholder":"Select Parent Projects","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetParents","data":editorComposite.clientsandprojects,"type":"POST"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"value":"7507,8979"});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Project</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header k-multiselect-clearable" deselectable="on" title="" style=""><div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" deselectable="on"><ul role="listbox" deselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="ProjectIds_taglist"><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">AZNN6A</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">AZNCC7</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">AZNAC7</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li></ul><input class="k-input" style="width: 30px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ProjectIds_taglist ProjectIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="595bbfd9-2484-42f3-9a63-cd5bc9a418f2"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span></div><select data-value-primitive="true" id="ProjectIds" multiple="multiple" name="ProjectIds" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="7847">AZNAC7</option><option value="8727">AZNBC7</option><option value="7753">AZNCC7</option><option value="8625">AZNGC7</option><option value="7845">AZNHC7</option><option value="7844">AZNKC7</option><option value="7508">AZNL6A</option><option value="8624">AZNMC7</option><option value="7506">AZNN6A</option><option value="7509">AZNN6B</option><option value="7752">AZNN6I</option><option value="8017">AZNN6Q</option><option value="7881">AZNN6X</option><option value="8980">AZNNA7</option><option value="9189">AZNNB7</option><option value="7756">AZNNC7</option><option value="9126">AZNNE7</option><option value="9242">AZNNI7</option><option value="9187">AZNNX7</option><option value="8726">AZNSC7</option><option value="7846">AZNVC7</option><option value="8623">AZNWC7</option></select><span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 31px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span></div><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ProjectIds").kendoMultiSelect({"dataBound":function() { editorComposite.set('projects') },"autoBind":false,"autoClose":false,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"ProjectNumber","dataValueField":"ProjectId","highlightFirst":true,"ignoreCase":true,"placeholder":"Select Projects","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetProjects","data":editorComposite.parents,"type":"POST"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"value":"7506,7753,7847"});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Package Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header k-multiselect-clearable" deselectable="on" title="" style=""><div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" deselectable="on"><ul role="listbox" deselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="PackageTypeIds_taglist"><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">DPS</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li><li class="k-button" deselectable="on"><span deselectable="on">DPS-V</span><span unselectable="on" aria-label="delete" class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></span></li></ul><input class="k-input" style="width: 30px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="PackageTypeIds_taglist PackageTypeIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="dc5f3f3e-9bab-4e0c-bf2e-27e0d0688e5b"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span></div><select data-val="true" data-val-required="The Package Type field is required." data-value-primitive="true" id="PackageTypeIds" multiple="multiple" name="PackageTypeIds" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="410">DPS</option><option value="411">DPS-V</option><option value="412">OCV</option><option value="413">RD</option><option value="415">RFD-A</option><option value="414">RFD-D</option></select><span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 31px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span></div><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#PackageTypeIds").kendoMultiSelect({"dataBound":function() { editorComposite.set('packagetypes') },"autoBind":true,"autoClose":false,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"PackageTypeName","dataValueField":"PackageTypeId","highlightFirst":true,"ignoreCase":true,"placeholder":"Select Package Type","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetPackageTypes"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"value":"410,411"});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="package-editor-right col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Report</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ReportId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="792f64d4-dd9f-4487-8fb9-41d496c5c1a9" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Select Report Name</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input id="ReportId" name="ReportId" type="text" value="" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ReportId").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":true,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"ReportName","dataValueField":"ReportId","ignoreCase":true,"optionLabel":"Select Report Name","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetReports"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Package Format</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="PackageFormat_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="ea6e9399-3cf4-4c8f-8588-25375cf5ac6a" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">PDF</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Package Format field is required." id="PackageFormat" name="PackageFormat" type="text" value="432" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#PackageFormat").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":true,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"PackageFormatName","dataValueField":"PackageFormatId","ignoreCase":true,"value":"432","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetPackageFormats"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Image Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ImageTypeId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="204647ae-964d-4450-a35d-c687409e3e85" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Authorization</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input id="ImageTypeId" name="ImageTypeId" type="text" value="416" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ImageTypeId").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":true,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"ImageDesc","dataValueField":"ImageId","ignoreCase":true,"optionLabel":"Select Image Type","value":"416","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetImages"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Template Order</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox" style="min-width: 100%;"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default"><input type="text" class="k-formatted-value k-input" title="2" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="2" aria-disabled="false" style="min-width: 100%; display: inline-block;"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Template Order field is required." id="TemplateOrder" min="1" name="TemplateOrder" style="min-width: 100%; display: none;" type="text" value="2" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="1" class="k-input" aria-valuenow="2" aria-disabled="false"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning" style="display: none;"></span><span class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-link k-link-increase" aria-label="Increase value" title="Increase value"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-up"></span></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link k-link-decrease" aria-label="Decrease value" title="Decrease value"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span></span></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#TemplateOrder").kendoNumericTextBox({"decimals":0,"format":"n0"});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Stamp Page</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
             <input checked="checked" class="k-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Stamp Page field is required." id="StampPage" name="StampPage" type="checkbox" value="true"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="StampPage"> </label><input name="StampPage" type="hidden" value="false">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">One Time Per Package</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="k-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The One Time Per Package field is required." id="OneTimePerPackage" name="OneTimePerPackage" type="checkbox" value="true"><label class="k-checkbox-label" for="OneTimePerPackage"> </label><input name="OneTimePerPackage" type="hidden" value="false">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4">Template Setting</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="TemplateSetting_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="e0e595c8-03d5-4164-be27-5488ed9a6b0f" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Grouped per Claim</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Template Setting field is required." id="TemplateSetting" name="TemplateSetting" type="text" value="434" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#TemplateSetting").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":true,"autoWidth":true,"dataTextField":"PackageTemplateDesc","dataValueField":"PackageTemplateId","ignoreCase":true,"optionLabel":"Select Template Setting","value":"434","valuePrimitive":true,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Package/GetPackageTemplates"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="errors" style="color:red;padding-left:2em"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I am using unobtrusive validation:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `onclick` is already the default behavior, so not sure why you are setting it to `true`.  Also, [read the docs for the `onclick` option:  *"A boolean true is **not** a valid value."*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onclick)

Comment: 1)  show us the **RENDERED** HTML markup for the form.  2) Are you using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?  3)  jQuery Validate is NOT the "jQuery Validation Engine".  Edited tags.

Comment: I am using the unobtrusive validations plugin:

Comment: I have edited the post to include the requested information

Comment: The onclick was set to true during testing.  It was originally set to false, but wasn't working either.

Comment: If you’re using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, then your call to `.validate()` is going to be ignored because Unobtrusive constructs it for you.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case.  My validate is running, its just that the number of errors in the errorList is always 1.

Comment: You absolutely cannot be calling `.validate()` more than one time.  All subsequent calls are always ignored. When you use the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, its call to `.validate()` occurs first and yours will always be ignored.  That is how it works.  As far as your situation, apparently you are removing this form's validator from Unobtrusive, so when I asked if you're using Unobtrusive Validation, the correct answer probably should have been "no".

Comment: The only reason I added that code is because it wasn't validating anything when I didn;t have it included.

Comment: I think that's probably because you are killing Unobtrusive with this line:  `form1.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation")`.  I'm a jQuery Validate expert who knows very little about ASP, Kendo, etc., so I cannot help much with that side of it.

Comment: So an update.  When using Kendo controls, the system generates multiple input fields for certain controls types.  Only one of the fields that is generated has the name property.  This is causing a 'Name is missing' error and the validation and is breaking.  I'm not really sure if I should consider this a kendo problem or a validation problem, but either way it doesn't seem to work.  In my mind, the validation should ignore any field that doesn't have the relevant validation attributes.  Thanks for the help, but I'll just validate on the server.

Comment: jQuery Validate requires that all fields contain a `name` attribute.  If Kendo cannot properly render HTML that contains all the requisite attributes then that certainly is a Kendo issue.  After all, jQuery has nothing to do with how your server-side code is generating the markup.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs for `showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors):

> A custom message display handler. Gets the map of errors as the first
>   argument and an array of errors as the second, called in the context
>   of the validator object. **The arguments contain only those elements
>   currently validated**, which can be a single element when doing
>   validation on focusout or keyup.

By definition above, you will only have the errors for the elements **currently** being validated, not the whole form.  The new map of messages does not retain the previous messages after new validation is completed. If one field is validated, then the map only contains the message for the one field, etc.

Refer to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599142/594235

Instead try the [`wrapper` and `errorLabelContainer`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper) options, which, when used together, were designed to automatically keep an updated list of pending messages for the whole form...

```
wrapper: "li",  // <- the LABEL will be inside of this
errorLabelContainer: "#errorSummaryList",  // <- your UL element
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/y9o8du3q/](https://jsfiddle.net/y9o8du3q/)**

Comment: Id added the following and removed the show errors (still only validating 1 field): **errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
        wrapper: "li",
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function () { alert("Submitted!") }**

Comment: Also, I have tried manually adding rules into the validation (It ignores these rules and only validates the first field):  **rules: {
            "TemplateOrder": { required: true },
            "TemplateSetting": { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            "TemplateOrder": {
                required: "Please enter a template order."
            },
            "TemplateSetting": {
                required: "Please enter a template setting."
            }
        },
        etc...**

Comment: I tried changing the kendo type on the TemplateOrder to TextBoxFor instead of IntegerTextBoxFor.  When I did this it validate 2 fields instead of 1.  This indicates the issue isn't with the validation but it is instead with the Controls.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This unfortunately was cause by the html elements missing the name attribute.
Without the name attribute the validation was not functioning appropriately.